# iOS Scroll Issues with RMarkown document published at RStudio Connect

Tags: ios, r, shiny, r-markdown

This is my 1-st question at StackOverflow.

**Description**

I'm trying to test RStudio Connect 1.4.2-15-x86_64.rpm.

- I write Rmarkdown document which is well compiled as on Windows (dev platform) as on CentOS (server platform). This document is much longer than web screen height.
- While content of document well scrolled on Android mobile and all PC platforms and browsers, I have issue with vertical page scrolling at mobile iOS (iPhone & iPad). Content outside physical window is hidden.
- I tried all popular browser on iOS like Safari, Opera, Yandex, Mozilla. The same situation happened in all browsers. It feels that error is at iOS web rendering engine level. Looks like issue '[IPad Scroll Issues with Fixed Content](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2015/jun/05/ipad-scroll-issues-with-fixed-content)'.

**Question**: How I can workaround it at R\package\css\pandoc level?

P.S. I've created short [video snapshot](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/2kfxpf6w8m00q0s/AABjt7G-lY8LurnPYlwXF4PIa?dl=0) with Good scrolling at Desktop browser and Broken scrolling at iOS browser.

Comment: Same issue over here. But not only for rmarkdown docs, also complete shiny apps.